# how to use bert in android or java to erlang backend?

Tags: java, android, mobile, erlang, bert-rpc

I want to use erlang as android backend, but the n2o/erlang framework use a bert/websocket.
Can I use bert in android to it's backend ?
Is there some library for android or java ?

Comment: I got an answer from github: [bert_java](https://github.com/hilarycheng/bert_java)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://clojars.org/bert-java-serialization) library published in Clojars (i.e.  the Maven of the Clojure world), but I couldn't find the source code though and its last version is from May 28, 2013 so I'm not really sure what is its status.

Another option is using the [C++ library](https://github.com/ruediger/libbert) through [JNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) in your android project, creating a wrapper around it and using it to encode/decode BERT data, though I guess it would be a PITA.

For what it's worth, there is a Clojure implementation [here](https://github.com/trotter/bert-clj), though not ready for production.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BERT Android library for Android and java.

https://github.com/pankajsoni19/AndroidBert